# Solving $10\sin(2x)=4.0625-\sin^2(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

Please if anyone can help me find $x$ in this equation:

$$10\sin(2x)=4.0625-\sin^2(x)$$

Comment: Divide both sides by $\cos^2x$ or $\sin^2x$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you halve the argument in the first term and add a $\cos^2x+\sin^2x$ factor to the constant term, you make this a homogeneous equation, which you can deal with passing to the tangent.
\begin{eqnarray}
20\sin x \cos x &=& \frac{65}{16}(\cos^2x + \sin^2x)-\sin^2x\\
320\sin x \cos x &=& 65\cos^2 x + 49 \sin^2x.
\end{eqnarray}
Divide by $\cos^2x$ (after checking $\cos x= 0$ is not a valid solution) and obtain
$$49 \tan^2x-320\tan x +65 =0$$

Comment: Very nice. I think this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak :) I saw your discussion below your answer, but I guess OP isn't much interested himself to his own question.

Comment: Of course for a rigorous solution, one should ensure that no solution of $\cos x =0$ satisfies the original equation.

Comment: @Deepak correct. but since it's a second degree homogeneous equation, $\cos^2x = 0$ would require also $\sin^2 x = 0$ ,which is impossibile. Maybe I should explicitely say that.

Comment: Yes, I feel it should be explicitly stated. But otherwise, perfect. :)

Comment: @Deepak, done !

Comment: Looks good ! :)

Comment: Thank you. It is really a perfect solution.

Comment: By dividing right away by $c^2$ the term $\frac 1{c^2}=1+t^2$ appears, it also worth notifying this frequent substitution. Of course this gives exactly the same result, I just wanted to circumvent the somehow artificial replacement of $1$ by $c^2+s^2$ as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

$10\sin(2x)=4.0625-\sin^2(x)$

Use the double angle identity to recast $\sin^2 x$ in terms of $\cos 2x$:

$10\sin(2x)=4.0625-\frac 12(1-\cos 2x)$

$20\sin 2x - \cos 2x = 7.125$

Now recast the left hand side as $R\sin(2x - \alpha)$ following [this](https://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php) method, after which the solution should become obvious.

Comment: Simpler as my hint is this not. Using the Weierstrass substitution we get $$-65\,{t}^{4}-640\,{t}^{3}-66\,{t}^{2}+640\,t-65=0$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Are you saying your method is simpler? How so? That quartic does not have an easy exact solution.

Comment: But the theory for the other approach is not so easy.

Comment: Both methods are not easy!

Comment: I disagree. It is possible to use the method I've presented to give an answer in terms of the arcsine of a simple surd plus the arctangent of a rational almost immediately. With the Weierstrass sub, the quartic you end up with (and I'm taking your word for it here as I feel it's unnecessarily tedious and I don't want to work it out your way) needs either a difficult analytic solution in really messy radicals or a numerical solution, neither of which feel very satisfactory to me. Anyway, it's up to the asker to decide which method is better, but it seems you've deleted your answer (why?).

Comment: Not to mention, your final answer is not even those messy radicals - you still need to take the arctangent of each of those solutions.